# Where to store connection string? And change it programmatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am newbie in asp.net. and I need to store some string (aka connection string) permanently. It is looks well if I store it to  in web.config.

I need that user can modify it string via web ui. Than is why I must do it programmatically. But ApplicationPoolIdentity doesn't have writing rights to web.config. And I don't want to bother admins so that they grant rights.

I thought I can store data in some file in {user}\AppData but by default App Pool doesn't load user profile. **UPDATE** It's not quite right. I don't know exactly what default settings is. But I still can not get access to folder. See my paired [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45821839/6113678) **UPDATE2** I have access to LocalAppData now and can store my connection string. I had to write an installer who enable loading user profile. But I think this is too complex solution.

So where I can store on string and modify it programmatically without any administration of IIS?

Comment: There are multiple options you can either store it in database, or make a text file to store your data and if you have multiple configuration make an xml file in your project directory and store you data in xml nodes.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  You believe changing the connection string will solve some other problem you aren't telling us.  There are millions if not billions of asp.net applications that don't need this feature.  What does this solve?

Answer (score 0):

Storing connection strings in database seems illogical to me, as you have to connect to database to read the connection string.

Better place is `web.config`. There are chances that if you change connection string, then IIS will restart your application but it will be good because you will change connection string when you have change your database server's location or password. IIS restart will ensure that new connection string is used in every where.

Comment: I want to use web ui only.

Comment: @Webprojectbuilder Please see our advertising policy, [how to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).