# GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) returns empty string

Tags: asp.net, iis

I saw many old questions like this but it is not my case.

Asp.net application is running in AppPool (iis in win10) with 'load user profile' enabled.

And nevertheless Environment.GetFolderPath(ApplicationData or LocalApplicationData) returns an empty string. CommonApplicationData returns correct folder.

I ensure that {user}\AppData is exist on disk.

So, question: how can I get not empty string for AppData?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not enough to enable `'loadUserProfile'` option in IIS!

You have to enable another one option. This is `'setProfileEnvironment'`. I didn't find IIS UI to change it.

Open file in `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` and add or change attributes for your application pool.

```
<configuration>
    <system.applicationHost>
        <applicationPools>
            <add name="YourPool" >
                <processModel  
                 loadUserProfile="true" 
                 setProfileEnvironment="true"/>
```

And after that you can get ApplicationData or LocalApplicationData path!

Comment: What's funny is that in the documentation, they're lying saying that by default that setting is set to true.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel